# New fill - two different meshes

Tags: vertices, faces

I have removed a face inside one of my meshes, and now I'm trying to create a new one but based on 2 vertices from another mesh. In my tutorial it fills if with "F" key and creates new "quad", but at me it fills whole all area, not just 4 vertices. 
May be the reason is that I have a newer Blender version 2.81 while tut version is 2.79(smth). So I can't get a new fill with quad (pictures added). What am I doing wrong or not getting here? Thank you in advance.

[image]
[image]Fc.jpg
[image] 
[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you are trying to create a face from verts in two separate meshes which won't work. You need to join "inside" and "metal" into a single object, then you should be able to create the face.

Comment: That was so obvious )) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have vertices, edges or faces across different objects. Different objects need to be joined first. Select both objects and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

In case you forgot to "join" mashes here is a useful [link](https://all3dp.com/2/blender-how-to-merge-objects) on how to do it Thanks!